# String input into String array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student {
    private String []  first;
    private String [] last;
    private String [] HKID;
    private String[] SID;
    private int []Exam;
    private int num;
    Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);

    public Student (String f, String l, String h, String s, int e, int n){
        System.out.println("Please enter number of students:");
        n =  kb.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i >n; i++){
            System.out.println("First name:");
            f = kb.next();
            first = new String[f];
            System.out.println("Last name:");
            l=kb.next();
            last= new String[l];
            System.out.println("HKID:");
            h=kb.next();
            HKID=new String[h];
            System.out.println("SID:");
            s=kb.next();
            SID=new String [s];
            System.out.println("Final exam score:");
            e=kb.nextInt();
            Exam=new int [e];
    }

    public String[] getFirst(){return first;}
    public String [] getLast(){return last;}
    public String [] getHKID(){return HKID;}
    public String [] getSID(){return SID;}
    public int [] getExam(){return Exam;}
    public void setFirst(String [] f){f=first;}
    public void setLast(String [] l){l=last;}
    public void setHKID(String [] h){h=HKID;}
    public void setSID(String [] s){s= SID;}
    public void setExam(int [] e){e=Exam;}
}
```

I am creating a code that first asks user how many students are in the class. From this it asks several details to enter for each student and stored in their respective arrays. Problem: I can't put enter a String variable into my String array. I can't think of any way around this. Please help.

Comment: Change your for lopp with `for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)` and it should work.

Comment: Still can't enter a String value into my String array. It reports cannot convert String to int for f,l,h,s in the constructor respectively

Answer (score 4):

Problem is :

```
    for(int i=0;i >n; i++)
    {
    }
```

Write This :

```
       for(int i=0;i <n; i++)
       {
       // your code 
       }
```

You are not initialize a String array .

```
 import java.util.*;

 class Student 
 {
 private String []  first;
 private String [] last;
 private String [] HKID;
 private String[] SID;
 private int []Exam;
 private int num;
 Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);
 int n=0;
public Student (){

   System.out.println("Please enter number of students:");
     n =  kb.nextInt();
     first = new String[n];
     last= new String[n];
     HKID=new String[n];
     SID=new String [n];
     Exam=new int [n];

     for(int i=0;i <n; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("First name:");
        first[i]= kb.next();
        System.out.println("Last name:");
        last[i]=kb.next();
        System.out.println("HKID:");
        HKID[i]=kb.next();
        System.out.println("SID:");
        SID[i]=kb.next();
        System.out.println("Final exam score:");
        Exam[i]= kb.nextInt();
      }
  System.out.print("Student Detail");

  System.out.print("First Name \t Last Name \t HKID \t SID \t Final exam score \n " );

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    System.out.print(first[i]+"\t"+last[i]+"\t"+HKID[i]+"\t"+SID[i]+"\t"+Exam[i]);
    System.out.println();
   }
 }
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Student();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still can't enter a String value into my String array. It reports cannot convert String to int for f,l,h,s in the constructor respectively

Answer (score 0):

Firstly initialize all arrays to size 'n' which you are reading outside for loop.

Then,Inside your for loop you can directly mention

```
for(i=o;i<n;i++){
   System.out.println("First name:");
   f = kb.next();
   first[i] = f;
}
```

kb.next() returns a String object so u can also directly do `first[i]=kb.next();`

The main issue with your code here is that you are passing string object to define size of array which is incorrect (i.e here `new String[f]`)

Hope this helps!

All The Best!

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. If you are looking for some extra cash, I am in need of some help with the rest of my java project. Let me know if you can or are willing to help.

Comment: accepting the answer is the way of telling that answer really helped at stackoverflow :P
and inbox me your requirements at vihar1903@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

**First** , I don't konw why you create the constructor like this

```
   public Student (String f, String l, String h, String s, int e, int n)
```

Meanwhile , you override each parameter in it

**Second** , one way to convert a String parameter into array is

```
char arr1[]=new char[len1];
arr1=s1.toCharArray()
```

String[] is an array of String , and char[] is a array of char ,which means a String.